# Showing last to first mysql entries

Tags: mysql, records

I'm currently working on a website and I have a table called `appeals` that I want to display the latest records from. What would the query be to do this? So instead of displaying first to last I want it to display last to first.

The current query I have is:

`$query = "SELECT id,user,title,reason,appealdate,closed FROM appeals WHERE closed='0'";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just revert an order with `ORDER BY id DESC`:

```
  SELECT id,user,title,reason,appealdate,closed
    FROM appeals
   WHERE closed='0'
ORDER BY id DESC
```